# Why gif file won't delete when I use directory.delete?

Tags: c#, directory, gif

I need your help to solve my problem.

I use gif files in my application. I can add an image in a folder (the folder is created when it doesn't exist). I can also remove the gif image and the folder will be deleted.

I use `Directory.Delete(string path, bool recursive);` to delete the gif file. The following problem is the gif image is use by another process but I don't know why.

The syntax works when I use normal file. The problem is only when I use gif file.

Someone can help me please ?

Comment: How did you check if it's used by another process not yours ?

Comment: I have an IOException and my program crash

Comment: ok, but you didn't reasearch if it's your process or not - use handle.exe - if it's yours then maybe you didn't dispose file or it's GC issue (not called yet) - if another than you can do nothing

Comment: I checked and no it's not the case.. It seems like my gif is running even if I deleted it

Comment: The IOException that you get is "System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'xyxy.gif' because it is being used by another process."?

Comment: If it is, use handle.exe (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) and inspect what process has open your file @YohanQuiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the solution, my image was in the BackgroundImage of my PictureBox but the image was not null before deleting it so there was a confusion. I removed the BackgroundImage = null line and my program works.

It was not my program so  it is complicated to debugging.

Thanks for those who helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the "File.Delete(String path)" method. For more information visit

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.delete?view=netcore-3.1

the "File" class can also be used for other IO operations

if the file is open in another proccess make sure to close the file before deleting it using "File.Close()".

Comment: I tried also this solution, I deleted first the file and then the Directory but I have the same problem when the file is deleted